# mongodb aggregation select specific document in group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need a bit help with mongodb aggregation.

first I have a $match to get filter some specific documents.

then I group by a field I need them grouped in.

the group I need to select a document where field value is ... and get that document as main data.

```
{"$match": {"$and": [
  {chain: chain},
  {dex: dex}
]}};

{$group: {
 _id: "$pairAddress",
 allChange: {"$push": "$$ROOT"},
 baseToken: {$last: '$baseToken'},
 txCount: {the document with timeframe inside this group 86400.txCount}
}},
{$sort: {txCount: -1}}
{$skip: 0}
{$limit: 100}
```

the group consist of documents with different timeframes, I need to somehow select a specific timeframe and add fields to the group from that timeframe. for example each timeframe has a different amount of txCount after group I want to sort by txCount and limit the amount and use skip for some pagination.

the problem is in selecting a document from that group with the specific timeframe.
anyone who could help me a bit to the right direction that would be awesome.

Here an example of how data is stored in the database and what I would like the result to be.

```
const document = {
    _id: '3567356735672467',
    pairAddress: '0x45jk6v34jy5634jkh5v6kj4h5v62j4h56',  // group by pair address
    baseToken: '0x456jn345k6hb4k5h6b3khb65k3hb56k3h4b6',
    resolution: 86400, // a pair address has 6 documents with each a own timeframe 300, 900, 1800, 3600, 43200, 86400
    base0: true,
    txCount: 26,
    buyCount: 10,
    sellCount:16,
    buyVolume: '2342354.345',
    sellVolume: '1234.34',
    volume: '1232352.345',
    change: '12.34',
    positive: true,
    time: 1676865981,
    chain: 'ETH',
    dex: 'SUS',
    price: '12.45',
};

const result = [
    {
        _id: "0x45jk6v34jy5634jkh5v6kj4h5v62j4h56",
        allChange: {"$push": "$$ROOT"}, // array of all documents/timeframes for a pairAddress
        selectedTxAmount: 26, // this needs to be the document with selected timeframe example 86400, selected from the group is must match the pairAddress
    }
];
```

Maybe its possible to change the aggregation to make it work and faster.

match all timeframes, dex and chain.

sort by txCount.

skip X amount.

limit to 100

and return all document with a field containing all timestamps per the pairAddress left after the aggregation.

Currently thanks to @1sina1 I got this and it works.

```
{"$match": {"$and": [
    {"chain": chain},
    {"dex": dex}
]}},

{$group: {
    _id: "$pairAddress",
    allChange: {"$push": "$$ROOT"},
    baseToken: {$last: '$baseToken'},
    txCount: {
        "$push": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": [
                "$resolution",
                43200
              ]
            },
            "then": "$txCount",
            "else": "$$REMOVE"
          }
        }
    }
}},

{$sort: {txCount: -1}},
{$skip: parseInt(page) * 100},
{$limit: 100},
```

But I think there might be a way to do it just a bit different now we first group all (which is about 20k documents) I am only interested in 100, so maybe first match to timeframe/resolution then sort, skip, limit and then I just need from those 100 pairAddress all the according timeframes/resolutions for each as a flied allChange.

```
{$match: {resolution: 86400}},
{$sort: {txCount: -1}},
{$limit: 100},

{
  from: "CHANGE",
  localField: "pairAddress",
  foreignField: "pairAddress",
  as: "changeInfo"
}

{$group: {
 _id: "$pairAddress",
 allChange: {???}, // I need the changeInfo in here
}}
```

this is the fastest way to get the the ranking I want, now I only need to get a array of all items from the changeInfo, in the compass aggregations it does show all resolutions per pair in the lookup, how to get them all into a field in group?

Another update:

I got the whole aggregation working to get all data with

```
 {$match:{
    resolution: 86400
}},

{$sort: {
    "txCount": -1
}},

{$skip: page},

{$limit: 100},

{$lookup: {
    from: "CHANGE",
    localField: "pairAddress",
    foreignField: "pairAddress",
    as: "changeInfo"
}},

{$lookup: {
    from: "PAIRS",
    localField: "pairAddress",
    foreignField: "pairAddress",
    as: "pairInfo"
}},

{$lookup: {
    from: "TOKENS",
    localField: "baseToken",
    foreignField: "tokenAddress",
    as: "tokenInfo"
}},

{$group: {
    _id: "$pairAddress",
    allChange: {$push: "$changeInfo"},
    token: {$push: "$tokenInfo"},
    pair: {$push: "$pairInfo"},
    txCount: {$last: "$txCount"},
    sellCount: {$last: "$buyCount"},
    buyCount: {$last: "$sellCount"},
    buyVolume: {$last: "$buyVolume"},
    sellVolume: {$last: "$sellVolume"},
    volume: {$last: "$volume"},
}},

{$sort: {
    "txCount": -1
}},
```

the result needs a bit cleanup.

```
{
  "_id": "0x16b9a82891338f9bA80E2D6970FddA79D1eb0daE",
  "allChange": [
    [
      {
        "_id": "0x16b9a82891338f9bA80E2D6970FddA79D1eb0daE/BSC/300",
        "base0": false,
        "baseToken": "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c",
        "buyCount": 111,
        "buyVolume": "15250.563727821701725512",
        "chain": "BSC",
        "change": "0.00",
        "dex": "PCS",
        "pairAddress": "0x16b9a82891338f9bA80E2D6970FddA79D1eb0daE",
        "positive": true,
        "price": "308.93963",
        "resolution": 300,
        "sellCount": 110,
        "sellVolume": "13654.604027759109523767",
        "time": 1676200616,
        "txCount": 221,
        "volume": "28905.167755580811249279"
      },
      {
        "_id": "0x16b9a82891338f9bA80E2D6970FddA79D1eb0daE/BSC/900",
        "base0": false,
        "baseToken": "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c",
        "buyCount": 111,
        "buyVolume": "15250.563727821701725512",
        "chain": "BSC",
        "change": "0.00",
        "dex": "PCS",
        "pairAddress": "0x16b9a82891338f9bA80E2D6970FddA79D1eb0daE",
        "positive": true,
        "price": "308.93963",
        "resolution": 900,
        "sellCount": 110,
        "sellVolume": "13654.604027759109523767",
        "time": 1676200616,
        "txCount": 221,
        "volume": "28905.167755580811249279"
      },
      {
        "_id": "0x16b9a82891338f9bA80E2D6970FddA79D1eb0daE/BSC/1800",
        "base0": false,
        "baseToken": "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c",
        "buyCount": 613,
        "buyVolume": "108562.512410928690002345",
        "chain": "BSC",
        "change": "-0.13",
        "dex": "PCS",
        "pairAddress": "0x16b9a82891338f9bA80E2D6970FddA79D1eb0daE",
        "positive": false,
        "price": "308.98069",
        "resolution": 1800,
        "sellCount": 649,
        "sellVolume": "154510.951381186350314059",
        "time": 1676200580,
        "txCount": 1262,
        "volume": "263073.463792115040316404"
      },
      {
        "_id": "0x16b9a82891338f9bA80E2D6970FddA79D1eb0daE/BSC/3600",
        "base0": false,
        "baseToken": "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c",
        "buyCount": 768,
        "buyVolume": "196748.75108068135728983",
        "chain": "BSC",
        "change": "0.00",
        "dex": "PCS",
        "pairAddress": "0x16b9a82891338f9bA80E2D6970FddA79D1eb0daE",
        "positive": true,
        "price": "308.93963",
        "resolution": 3600,
        "sellCount": 864,
        "sellVolume": "194775.974213770973022082",
        "time": 1676200616,
        "txCount": 1632,
        "volume": "391524.725294452330311912"
      },
      {
        "_id": "0x16b9a82891338f9bA80E2D6970FddA79D1eb0daE/BSC/21600",
        "base0": false,
        "baseToken": "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c",
        "buyCount": 1350,
        "buyVolume": "296571.005904020006044333",
        "chain": "BSC",
        "change": "-0.21",
        "dex": "PCS",
        "pairAddress": "0x16b9a82891338f9bA80E2D6970FddA79D1eb0daE",
        "positive": false,
        "price": "308.93963",
        "resolution": 21600,
        "sellCount": 1407,
        "sellVolume": "373288.099098334015044952",
        "time": 1676200616,
        "txCount": 2757,
        "volume": "669859.105002354021089285"
      },
      {
        "_id": "0x16b9a82891338f9bA80E2D6970FddA79D1eb0daE/BSC/86400",
        "base0": false,
        "baseToken": "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c",
        "buyCount": 21899,
        "buyVolume": "5131326.976429540799924637",
        "chain": "BSC",
        "change": "0.00",
        "dex": "PCS",
        "pairAddress": "0x16b9a82891338f9bA80E2D6970FddA79D1eb0daE",
        "positive": true,
        "price": "308.93963",
        "resolution": 86400,
        "sellCount": 22944,
        "sellVolume": "5114326.075301667158623017",
        "time": 1676200616,
        "txCount": 44843,
        "volume": "10245653.051731207958547654"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "token": [
    [
      {
        "_id": "63e7562a868638cab253e25e",
        "tokenAddress": "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c",
        "chain": "BSC",
        "decimal": 18,
        "name": "Wrapped BNB",
        "symbol": "WBNB",
        "totalSupply": "3797186526384316251962291"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "pair": [
    [
      {
        "_id": "63e7562a868638cab253e263",
        "pairAddress": "0x16b9a82891338f9bA80E2D6970FddA79D1eb0daE",
        "base0": false,
        "baseToken": "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c",
        "baseTokenDecimals": 18,
        "chain": "BSC",
        "dex": "PCS",
        "liquidity": {
          "token0": "73888123570331747329731186",
          "token1": "239135081583982174148465"
        },
        "name": "WBNB/USDT",
        "quoteToken": "0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955",
        "quoteTokenDecimals": 18,
        "stable": true,
        "version": "V2"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "txCount": 44843,
  "sellCount": 21899,
  "buyCount": 22944,
  "buyVolume": "5131326.976429540799924637",
  "sellVolume": "5114326.075301667158623017",
  "volume": "10245653.051731207958547654"
}
```

the fields where I $push it creates an array inside an array how to get rid of that. Then also the fields I use $push, I only need some specific fields from those.

example: from tokenInfo, I only need supply, name and img. the rest is not needed how to accomplish that?

Comment: Can you add some input documents and the corresponding expected output?

Comment: I added some examples

Comment: Would you be more explicit about _"somehow select a specific timeframe"_?  It's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: does [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g210HTfaYhe) answer your question?

Comment: @1sina1 this does indeed work, but its very slow, it takes all documents first, is it possible to first select the 100 sorted by txCount in a group and then add only for those 100 the according timeframes per pairAddress?

Comment: @1sina1 I updated my question with another last part to get the best result, maybe you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while and got some help of chatGPT, but here is the perfect solution for my problem.

```
{$match:{
    resolution: 86400
}},

{$sort: {
    "txCount": -1
}},

{$skip: page},

{$limit: 100},

{$lookup: {
    from: "CHANGE",
    let: { pair: "$pairAddress" },
    pipeline: [
        {$match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$pairAddress", "$$pair"] } }},
        {$project: { resolution: 1, change: 1, _id: 0 }},
        {$sort: { resolution: -1 }},
        {$group: {
            _id: "$resolution",
            change: {$first: "$change"}
        }},
        {$sort: { _id: 1 }},
        {$project: {
            resolution: "$_id",
            change: 1,
            _id: 0
        }}
    ],
    as: "changeInfo"
}},

{$lookup: {
    from: "PAIRS",
    localField: "pairAddress",
    foreignField: "pairAddress",
    as: "pairInfo"
}},

{$lookup: {
    from: "TOKENS",
    localField: "baseToken",
    foreignField: "tokenAddress",
    as: "tokenInfo"
}},


{$group: {
    _id: "$pairAddress",
    allChange: {$push: '$changeInfo' },
    token: {$push: { $arrayElemAt: ['$tokenInfo', 0] }},
    pair: {$push: { $arrayElemAt: ['$pairInfo', 0] }},
    txCount: {$last: "$txCount"},
    sellCount: {$last: "$buyCount"},
    buyCount: {$last: "$sellCount"},
    buyVolume: {$last: "$buyVolume"},
    sellVolume: {$last: "$sellVolume"},
    volume: {$last: "$volume"},
}},


{$project:{
    allChange: { $arrayElemAt: ['$allChange', 0] },
    token: { $arrayElemAt: ['$token', 0] },
    pair: { $arrayElemAt: ['$pair', 0] },
    txCount:  "$txCount",
    sellCount: "$buyCount",
    buyCount: "$sellCount",
    buyVolume: "$buyVolume",
    sellVolume: "$sellVolume",
    volume: "$volume",
}},

{$sort: {
    "txCount": -1
}},
```

Initially the problem I was stuck was getting an array of change data in the group. I got a solution for that problem, but the aggregation was so slow(27 seconds) I kept searching and asking, but not much help here. finally with a lot of patience and ai I got the perfect query which takes under 2 seconds to load.

Comment: Specifying `localField` and `foreignField` and then performing the exact equivalent `"$match"` in the `pipeline` is redundant, yes?

Comment: yes, you're right.

Comment: So, maybe not _"perfect"_.  ;-)

Comment: Now it is... :p

Comment: Well, you may want to look at `buyCount`/`sellCount` obfuscation, array creation and then only keeping first element,... IMHO, almost every time a "_perfect_ technical solution" is presented, it's more about persuasion (e.g., marketing) than reality. Having a "perfect technical solution" fails to recognize opportunities for improvement.

Comment: You're right. Saying its perfect make you stop trying to make it better. And there is planty of room for improvement.